# Removing hard disk read only mode

Tags: permissions, fsck, read-only

To solve a problem with booting of my OS, I ran the command,

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1 -y
```

After that my root directory has been set in read only mode. I am not able to update my system. Also, I am not able to remove or install applications.

How can I change the read only mode to default mode.

Comment: Is that a sign of disk failure?

Comment: I don't know. But I'm able to read data. If somehow I get the commands to change hard disk permissions to write mode, then error can be fixed.

Comment: Is not as simple as that, a system doesn't just become read-only by choice and can't just be changed from the command line. If you didn't mess with your `/etc/fstab` then it's most likely the case, a backup of data would be useful!

Comment: What if I remount an already mounted filesystem without unmounting it like running the command <code>mount -o remount, rw /</code> from recovery mode.

Answer (score 1):

Errors are being detected during mount and the system is doing what it is told in `fstab` in order to give you the chance to fix it properly.

In `fstab` look for the line where the root is mounted.

It will look something like this:

```
UUID=a934c627-6f1a-498b-a857-1294108c7418 / ext3 errors=remount-ro
```

which tells the system that if there are errors detected, to mount it as `ro`

> From the mount (8) man page
>
> errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}
>
> Define the behaviour when an error is encountered.  (Either ignore errors
>   and just  mark  the  filesystem  erroneous and continue, or remount the
>   filesystem read-only, or panic and halt the system.)  The default is set in
>   the  filesystem superblock, and can be changed using tune2fs(8).

---

Boot from your Ubuntu installation media and run another `fsck` on / to try to clean up the file system so it does not detect errors at mount time.  There are situations where `fsck` needs to be run more than once.

You can also change the line in `fstab` to `errors=continue`.